# Get stuck when using java api to connect Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

My local environment:

OS X 10.9.2, Hbase-0.94.17, Java 1.6

My Hbase mode: standalone

I was able to do operation in shell, but when I used java api, it did not work.

My java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


public class MyLittleHBaseClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.addResource("/Users/apple/Documents/tools/hbase-0.94.17/conf/hbase-site.xml");

    HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");

    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));

    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
      Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));

    table.put(p);

    Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
    Result r = table.get(g);
    byte [] value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"),
      Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));

    String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);
    System.out.println("GET: " + valueStr);

    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
    try {

      for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
        // print out the row we found and the columns we were looking for
        System.out.println("Found row: " + rr);
      }

    } finally {

      scanner.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is some of my conf doc:

###########################################hbase-env.sh:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'`
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

###########################################hbase-site.sh:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///Users/apple/Documents/tools/hbase-0.94.17/hbase-rootdir/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/Users/apple/Documents/tools/hbase-0.94.17/hbase-zookeeper/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

When I ran the java code above, I got the following information:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2014-03-31 13:20:15.037 java[873:1003] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
```

and then the console just stopped here and gave nothing more.(no more response)

Also I attach my /Users/apple/Documents/tools/hbase-0.94.17/logs/hbase-apple...local.log here:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxtBre5A8J61Y2k3SXNtNGs1WXM/edit
```

Thanks for your patient, your answer will be a great help to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your conf file "hbase-env.sh":
Instead of the lines that you are having :
`export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`
Add :
`-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=`
So the line will be 
`export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="`

Look here for the context :[Hadoop on OSX "Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134723/hadoop-on-osx-unable-to-load-realm-info-from-scdynamicstore)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the same problem, I post my log file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtBre5A8J61Y19hM21qdklJcXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RickieLau Change the line "for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next())" to "for(Result rr : scanner)" , and now check. By the way, whats the command you are using to run the program?

Comment: Actually when I debugged the .java in eclipse it did not come to "for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next())", it just stop and wait after "Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create()", I use Run as>Java Application to ran the .java , thank you.

Comment: Ok.one more check.. try through command line, may be you forgot to add proper jar files in eclipse.If my program is in /Users/Chandrakant/programs and hbase is at /Users/Chandrakant/hbase then I will run "javac -cp /Users/Chandrakant/hbase/hbase-0.94.jar:/Users/Chandrakant/hbase/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar MyLittleHBaseClient.java" and then "java -cp /Users/Chandrakant/hbase/hbase-0.94.jar:.:/Users/Chandrakant/hbase/lib/* MyLittleHBaseClient". you do the same as per your username. And then see what happens?

Comment: Thank u very much! It turned out to be that I add the wrong dependency in my pom.xml, now I add hbase-0.94.17 and hadoop-core-1.0.4 in my pom.xml and the program start to ran normally, but still I got some confusing problem, gosh...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800894/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticlog

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource("/Users/apple/Documents/tools/hbase-0.94.17/conf/hbase-site.xml");
```

if you add this in hbase-site.xml .

and add this to your  hbase-site.xml :

`<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
 </property>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the same problem, I post my log file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtBre5A8J61Y19hM21qdklJcXc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem.
I had config server name in hbase-site.xml rather than the IP,
and my java client also stuck in this situation.

So I set my client system host for the server name, and I solved this case.

Answer (score 0):

At first, You check clientPort in hbase-site.xml file:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2222</value>
</property>
```

And in java program: You must set clientPort the same as in hbase-site.xml file:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
```