# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, maven, log4j, hbase, slf4j

My local environment: OSX 10.9.2, java1.6

I use java api to connect hbase and maven to manage my project, I added Hbase-0.94.17 and Hadoop-core-1.0.4 into pom.xml, when I ran my .java program to connect Hbase I got the following error:

```
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<clinit>(ZooKeeper.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getZooKeeperWatcher(HConnectionManager.java:1505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:958)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:129)
    at org.geogit.storage.hbase.MyLittleHBaseClient.main(MyLittleHBaseClient.java:29)
```

Here is what I got after ran mvm dependency:tree

```
INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.2:tree (default-cli) @ geogit-hbase ---
[INFO] org.geogit:geogit-hbase:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.geogit:geogit-core:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- java3d:vecmath:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-api:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:0.9.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cloudera.htrace:htrace-core:jar:2.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.0.1:compile (version managed from 1.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.geogit:geogit-mongodb:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geogit:geogit-blueprints:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- colt:colt:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-java:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.tinkerpop:pipes:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.geogit:geogit-core:jar:tests:0.8-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
```

And here I attach my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.geogit</groupId>
    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.geogit</groupId>
  <artifactId>geogit-hbase</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>HBase Storage for GeoGit objects</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geogit</groupId>
      <artifactId>geogit-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.94.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- is this necessary? -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.boundlessgeo</groupId>
      <artifactId>blongo</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- is this necessary? -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geogit</groupId>
      <artifactId>geogit-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, I attach my dependency tree above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have `slf4j-api` and choose a SLF4J binding of corresponding version, and add them as dependencies in your own POM.  It is quite possibly some of your dependencies transitively resolve an incompatible version of SLF4J binding which caused the problem.  Find which library is bringing in the unwanted SLF4J binding (you can easily do so by `mvn dependency:tree`), and add corresponding exclusion in your dependency to that lib.

(Normally SLF4J binding shouldn't be declared in library.  It is in fact something wrong that you may want to report to the library developer once you found the actual cause)

---

Update

That's exactly what I am talking about:

From your dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.geogit:geogit-core:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile

.....

[INFO] +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
       .....
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
```

You got `slf4j-log4j12` binding from `hbase-client`, and that's version 1.6.1

However, `slf4j-api` you have in your project is version 1.7.5.  They are not compatible.

Proper way to solve is:

1. Exclude `slf4j-log4j12` from your dependency of `hbase-client`
2. Declare a compatible SLF4J binding in your own project

You should also report this as a bug to zookeeper/hbase developer as it is not appropriate for a library to include SLF4J binding as compile scope dependency.

Comment: I attach my dependency tree above. Something wrong?

Comment: Oh that is weird, I did add the Hbase-client-0.98.0 dependency once before, but I have deleted it few days ago and change to Hbase-0.94.17, I attach my pom.xml in Hbase module above, and I still got the problem. @Adrian Shum

Comment: Sorry my mistake, ignore the comment above, now I change my version Hbase dependency to Hbase-0.94.17, and I got slf4j-log4j12 binding from hbase-0.94.17 which version is 1.4.3, so here is the problem, I have to exclude slf4j-log4j12 from my dependency of hbase-0.94.17 and declare a compatible SLF4J binding in my own project, but meanwhile I need the other dependency from Hbase-0.94.17, how could I solve that? Thank you. @Adrian Shum

Comment: if you are doing an exclusion in your `hbase` dependency and exclude only `slf4j-log4j12`, it shouldn't stop Maven from transitively retrieving other dependencies of `hbase`

Comment: How can I exclude 'slf4j-log4j12' from Hbase-0.94.17.jar? Does it work if I just declare a new compatible SLF4J dependency in pom.xml and do nothing else? Sorry to ask so many question as Im quite new to Maven. @Adrian Shum