# NoSuchMethodError - org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withDummyCallSite

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to launch a Spark job (Spark 1.4.0) on a cluster. Both from the command line and Eclipse, I get an error about `withDummyCallSite` function being missing in Spark Utils class. In maven dependencies, I can see that spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar is loaded, which is supposed to include this function. I am running Java 1.7, same as the Java version against which the code was previously compiled. I can see on the Spark Master monitor that the job has launched, so it doesn't seem to be a firewall issue. Here is the error I see in the console (both from command line and Eclipse):

```
ERROR 09:53:06,314  Logging.scala:75 -- Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withDummyCallSite(Lorg/apache/spark/SparkContext;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2.buildScan(newParquet.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.buildScan(interfaces.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.planLater(QueryPlanner.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$HashAggregation$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:932)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.count(DataFrame.scala:1269)
```

(Log is truncated for brevity)

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Please check how your class is resolved by maven using keys (CNTR+Shift+T). Make sure that it is not resolved from two different jars in your classpath.

If your class is referred from any of the transitive dependencies, add the required jar as a direct dependency using the version you need.

You can refer to these links for more reference.

[mockito test gives no such method error when run as junit test but when jars are added manually in run confugurations, it runs well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962003/mockito-test-gives-no-such-method-error-when-run-as-junit-test-but-when-jars-are)

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800894/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticlog)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I double checked the contents of spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar (downloaded through the dependency I specified in pom.xlm), and withDummyCallSite function was indeed missing. I manually downloaded this jar from http://mvnrepository.com and replaced the jar, and the problem is now gone. It is the exact same version (2.10-1.4.0), not sure why the function was missing in the first place.

Comment: No problem! It's good to hear that changing the jar manually solved your problem. Actually in this kind of situation, you can directly delete the folder structure of your dependency (E.g. C:/Users/{your username}/.m2/reposirty/org/apache/spark) from local cahce/repo. After deleting this jar, maven downloads the new copy from your remote repository and you can get new copy of the specified version in your local repo.